# How to improve my app using TimeProfiler?

Tags: ios, objective-c, profiling, instruments, xcode-instruments

I am using TimeProfiler for the first time. And I have read RayWanderlich's [blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode) to get understanding of TimeProfiler.

How I can improve the performance in my app. I am showing the screenshots from the TimeProfiler that might help in analysing the SO's to understand where I am lacking. The time that is marked in the screenshot is increasing when I am scrolling through the Table View.

**Let me elaborate:**
My app opens and request feeds from the server and I am displaying them in `UITableView`. The time that I am worried about is in function
`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when the cell is displaying a time using `NSDateFormatter`.

I have used `NSDateFormatter` only once using `dispatch_once` GCD method.

Please check the screenshots. Any help is appreciated.

From Time Profiler:
[image: TimeProfiler]

Displaying where the time is spent:
[image]

Calling Utility method from Table View `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:
[image]

Comment: did you try with changing the code? it looks like normal operational time.

Comment: But the time is increasing when I am scrolling UITableView

Comment: Try to change the code for date formatter and try to run thing in mail thread only!

Comment: @Retro: what changes I must make. I have already optimized to use only one NSDateFormatter. But the function dateFromString and stringFromDate has to be used. No other option. Where should I optimize.